# QFont to QVariant conversion

Tags: qt

I want to convert a QFont to a QVariant and back

I know I can convert the QFont to a string. However there is NO constructor, for QFont from string, so I can't go back.

How can I got From QFont to QVariant and back?

Comment: Explain, what do you mean by converting QFont to QString, what do you want to do in the background?

Comment: There is a toString function in QFont. I simply want to store the QFont in a QVariantHash. So I can do that to the toString to store it but I don't know to to get it back, so to speak. I would expect QFont to have a constructor from string

Comment: QFont is supported by QVariant. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum . Use `QVariant::fromValue`, since there's no constructor (QFont is a gui type, while QVariant is a core type).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Here is a complete compilable working example of the complete procedure https://pastebin.com/V5VVq9WM

Comment: I recommend posting an answer to your solution.

Comment: Agreed. But it should be @JohannesSchaub-litb since he was the one that gave me the answer.